# Using IF AND to calculate based on one or more criteria

Tags: excel

Within a resource planner, my data has a row for each employee, and columns detailing the team they work for. Another column details the available days they will work in the year. The teams are also displayed along a row at the top, see below :

```
        A     |     B     |    C     |  D   |    E    |   F  |   G  |   
1    Employee |   Team 1  |  Team 2  | Days | Finance | Risk |  IT  |    
2  Employee 1 |  Finance  |          | 170  |         |      |      |
3  Employee 2 |  Risk     | Finance  | 170  |         |      |      |
4  Employee 3 |  Finance  |          | 170  |         |      |      |
5  Employee 4 |  IT       | Risk     | 170  |         |      |      |
6  Employee 5 |  IT       | Finance  | 170  |         |      |      |
```

I want to use columns E:G as a supply calculator per team. Therefore, the formula in cell E2 would be "=IF(B2=E1,D2,0)" and copied along the row, returning the 170 days under Finance and 0 under the rest.

The issue lies where an employee divides his time between two different teams. As you can see, some employees can work for 2 different teams (Employee 2 works for both Finance and Risk, for example). The formula in E3 would therefore need to be some kind of IF AND, where if a value is present in the Team 2 column (C), the value in the Days column (D) would be divided by two and split across the relevent team columns.

I've tried a few options, IF AND, nested IFS etc but cant seem to get the syntax correct. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps days are not granular enough. Maybe rethink your units of measure. One of my friends (yes - I have one!) said that the approach adopted in one of the places he worked was to break the (7.5 hour) day into 37 units (15 minutes each). These units were then chargeable to the clients.

Comment: @Paul - "One of my friends" implies you actually have more than one! :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Hmmm... Perhaps I should head of for a recount! ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E$1,$B2:$C2,0)),$D2/COUNTA($B2:$C2),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You actually want OR and COUNTA:

```
=IF(OR($B2=E$1,$C2=E$1),$D2/COUNTA($B2:$C2),0)
```

[image]